# Video.js plays ZLMediaKit HLS stream chugging and stopping in Chrome, but very fluency in Safari

Tags: http-live-streaming, video.js

I'm using `ZLMediaKit` to pull about 40 RTSP Surveillance Streams and transform them into HLS live streams in Server A. I'm also developing a VUE project to play all these HLS streams on web. I'm using `video.js` to play multiple HLS streams in one page. However, in Chrome, the streams are chugging, and cannot be played fluently even for a second. But in Mac Safari, the live streams are perfect. I've notice that during the play in Chrome, the `ZLMediaKit` logs a lot `Cookie Timeout` messages. It seems a COPS issue, but I have configured the proxy server in `vite.config.ts` to proxy the HLS requests. Could anyone please give me some advice?

Here's my Vue code:

```js
<template>
    <video ref="videoPlayer" class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered" />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import videojs from 'video.js'
import { onMounted, onUnmounted, ref, onUpdated } from 'vue'
import deviceStore from '@/store/index'
const devices = deviceStore()

const videoPlayer = ref()
let player: videojs.Player

const props = defineProps<{
  did: string
}>()

let url = `/video/${props.did}/hls.m3u8?uid=12345`

if (!url) {
  throw new Error(`${props.did} is not Camera or does not exist`)
}

let options: videojs.PlayerOptions = { 
  controls: true,
  muted: true,
  autoplay: true,
  fluid: true,
  controlBar: {
  volumePanel:false,
  },
  sources: [
    {
      src: url,
      type: "application/x-mpegURL",
    }
  ]
}

onMounted(() => {
  player = videojs(videoPlayer.value, options, () => {})
  videoPlayer.value = player  
})

onUpdated(() => {
  let newUrl = `/video/${props.did}/hls.m3u8?uid=12345`
  if (newUrl) {
    player.src(newUrl)
  } else {
    throw new Error(`${props.did} is not Camera or does not exist`)
  }
})

onUnmounted(() => {
  if (videoPlayer.value) {
    videoPlayer.value.dispose()
  }
})

</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.video-js {
  width: 99%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.1rem;
  margin-left: 0.2rem;
  color: #00153b;
  background-color:#ffffff00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;
  word-break: normal;
}
</style>
```